# Localstack start elasticsearch problem on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to install localstack on my AWS instance to which I SHH-ed. 
All the services except elasticsearch are installed properly. Here is the DEBUG=1 localstack start error:

I enabled all the localstack ports, installed the dependancies.

```
2019-07-25T09:20:54:INFO:werkzeug:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:4559/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-07-25T09:20:59:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:21:13:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:21:27:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:21:41:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:21:55:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:22:09:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:22:23:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:22:37:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:22:52:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:23:06:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2019-07-25T09:23:20:ERROR:localstack.services.es.es_starter: Elasticsearch health check failed (retrying...): TransportError(502, '') Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localstack/services/infra.py", line 416, in check_infra
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localstack/services/infra.py", line 413, in check_infra
    plugin.check(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localstack/services/infra.py", line 93, in check
    return self.check_function(expect_shutdown=expect_shutdown, print_error=print_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localstack/services/es/es_starter.py", line 72, in check_elasticsearch
    assert isinstance(out, six.string_types)
AssertionError
```